# Javascript for loop displaying more results than expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

When running the code below, the text inside the document.write runs 8 times and not 7 times as I was expected.

If I understand correctly, increment by 2 should display the positions:
`20+2, 22+2, 24+2, 26+2, 28+2, 30+2 and 32+2`.

Based on the results I get I assume it also displays the 34+2, which is 36. What I am missing? Thank you.

```
 x = 20;
 for (x = 20; x < 35; x += 2) {
   document.write("How many times will this loop execute?" + "<br/>");
 };
```

Comment: It will run for x having values 20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34 i.e. 8 times

Comment: You excluded first iteration..`20` is less than `35` and so on....

Comment: 8 times is correct...20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34...

Comment: Now I understand. I didn't have in mind the first iteration, which is indeed 20. Now it makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: 8 times proved. Check me out [at answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261402/javascript-for-loop-displaying-more-results-than-expected/36261498#36261498)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, The loop is correct in running 8 times.  Since no one stated the reason, it is this: the `x+=2` happens at the *end* of the loop, not at the beginning. So the loop will run for 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, and 34.

Comment: yeah exactly i run the code in https://jsfiddle.net/ and it works so maybe he declare the variable x in other place .... i guess

Comment: Thank you. I didn't take into consideration the first iteration, which is 20 - and not 36, like I intially thought. Just starting with Javascript so even simple things like these don't make much sense now.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how the [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) works.

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>
> final-expression: An expression to be evaluated **at the end of each loop** iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.

So your counter gets incremented at the end of the loop and the observed behaviour is correct. The loop gets executed for 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, and 34.

Answer (score 0):

It will run eight times, `x` iterating through every even number between 20 and 34 inclusive. You can write it like this if it helps:

```
var x = 20;
while (x <= 34) {
    // do something
    x += 2;
}
```

However, it is important to note that after the loop has run (whether you're using the `for` or `while` version), `x` will equal 36, since it is incremented to that before it finally fails the test; inside the loop, `x` will never equal 36. In terms of best practice, you should only really use a counter variable like `x` within the loop; this can be enforced by using the ES6 `let` keyword (which is block-scoped) like so (the example just prints out a list of the `x` values as DOM elements):

```js
function appendSpanCounter(i, end) {
    let el = document.createElement("span"),
        content = i.toString(10);

    if (i < end) content += ", ";

    (typeof el.textContent === "string") // ternary operator
        ? el.textContent = content
        : el.innerText = content;

    (document.body || document.querySelector("body")).appendChild(el);
}

for (let x = 20; x <= 34; x += 2) {
    appendSpanCounter(x, 34);
}
// x is now undefined here
```

Answer (score 0):

When start loop add +2 to x like below:

```
 x = 20;
 for (x = 20+2; x<35; x+=2) {
        document.write("How many times will this loop execute?" + "<br/>");
    };
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadimsajib/v7nuuvom/)

Answer (score 0):

**Script:**

```
x = 20;
count = 1;
for (x = 20; x < 35; x += 2){
  document.write("Execution: "+ (count++)+ "<br/>");
};
```

**Output**

The loop executes total 8 times.

> ```
> Execution: 1
> Execution: 2
> Execution: 3
> Execution: 4
> Execution: 5
> Execution: 6
> Execution: 7
> Execution: 8
> ```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/ktxjkqt9/) to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is executing 8 times, because is from 20 to 35 in 2 x 2

```js
x = 20;
for (x = 20; x < 35; x += 2) {
  document.write("Execute for " + x + " " + "<br/>");
};

/*
OUTPUT:

Execute for 20 
Execute for 22 
Execute for 24 
Execute for 26 
Execute for 28 
Execute for 30 
Execute for 32 
Execute for 34 
*/
```

If you want 7 times, you can change to **34**

```js
 x = 20;
 for (x = 20; x < 34; x += 2) {
   document.write("Execute for " + x + " " + "<br/>");
 };
```